# triggers and functions trouble

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm currently going through the growing pains of trying to learn about functions and triggers. I'm trying to do a problem from a book I'm reading , but i dont understand how to do certain parts.

using this table

```
create table movies (
    id      integer primary key,
    title   varchar(255) not null,
    year    integer
);

insert into movies values (1, 'The Croods', 2013);
insert into movies values (2, 'Now You See Me', 2013);
insert into movies values (3, 'Argo', 2012);
insert into movies values (4, 'Jurassic World', 2015);

create table discs (
    id          integer primary key,
    movie_id    integer not null references movies(id),
    type_id     integer references disc_types(id),
    price       decimal(10,2),
    available   boolean
);

insert into discs values (1, 1, 1, 1.59, 't');
insert into discs values (2, 1, 1, 1.59, 'f');
insert into discs values (3, 1, 2, 2.99, 'f');
insert into discs values (4, 2, 1, 1.29, 't');
insert into discs values (5, 2, 1, 1.29, 't');
insert into discs values (6, 2, 2, 2.99, 't');
insert into discs values (7, 3, 2, 2.59, 't');
insert into discs values (8, 3, 2, 2.59, 't');

create table customers (
    id      integer primary key,
    name    varchar(255),
    email   varchar(255)
);

insert into customers values (1, 'John', 'john@hotmail.com');
insert into customers values (2, 'Jane', 'jane@gmail.com');

create table rentals (
    id              integer primary key,
    customer_id     integer not null references customers(id),
    disc_id         integer not null references discs(id),
    date_rented     date,
    date_returned   date
);

insert into rentals values (1, 1, 7, '2013-10-01', '2013-10-03');
insert into rentals values (2, 2, 5, '2013-10-05', '2013-10-06');
insert into rentals values (3, 2, 2, '2013-11-02', null);
insert into rentals values (4, 2, 3, '2013-11-02', null);

create table ratings (
    customer_id integer not null references customers(id),
    movie_id    integer not null references movies(id),
    rating      integer,
  primary key (customer_id, movie_id)
);

insert into ratings values (1, 1, 1);
insert into ratings values (1, 2, 4);
insert into ratings values (1, 3, 5);
insert into ratings values (2, 1, 4);
```

my logic was that i would have the new values of the ratings table that were going to be inserted or updated and use those to compare to whats in the rentals table to see if that customer had rented that movie already, if they did then they could enter a rating. but i cant transfer that logic in this lol. unless there an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop inside the function complicates matters a bit, let's see if we can get rid of it. Your ratings table has a reference to customer and movie so we need a join.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO rented FROM rentals WHERE disc_id IN
  (SELECT id from discs INNER JOIN 
   rentals ON disc_id = discs.id where movie_id = new.movie_id)
  AND customer_id = new.customer_id
```

Right this should make the logic of your stored procedure a lot easier. I am now leaving you to finish it because this after all is a learning exercise.

You need this sort of a join because it's more efficient and simpler than the loop. The ratings table has a reference to the movie_id but the rentals table only has a disc_id thus to find out if the user has rented a particular movie, you need to join it through the disc table.

You will need to change the return values. ref: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

> Row-level triggers fired BEFORE can return null to signal the trigger
>   manager to skip the rest of the operation for this row (i.e.,
>   subsequent triggers are not fired, and the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE does
>   not occur for this row). If a nonnull value is returned then the
>   operation proceeds with that row value

And also note that you do not do an INSERT inside your trigger function. You just return a non null value for the insert to proceed.

Comment: You don't even need a count, you can use an `EXISTS (select * from rentals r where r.uid=new.uid and r.movie_id = new.movie)` in the function. (on second thought, this could even be a FK constraint ?)

Comment: alright , so this function is counting when the new info matches the old info right? so if it has matched its a 1, so if rented>0 then id create a new a record in the ratings? or am i miss reading this lol

Comment: Sorry for late reply, yes, you got it! or you can use exists like @wildplasser suggested.

Comment: @e4c5 alright one more thing , i dont get why we are inner joining the disc table , when we only want to see the customers who rented the movies. which would only be the rented and rated tables. wouldnt it just be a join on thoe 2 tables?

Comment: updated answer. briefly that's because your ratings does not have a direct reference to the rental table.

Comment: Just return non null (traditionally NEW) instead of doing the insert inside the trigger. That's what leads to the recursion and the stack depth being exeeded.

Comment: @e4c5 im not sure i understand what you mean. i tried putting new in the return , but im getting the same error

Comment: remove the INSERT from inside the trigger. It's not needed. Each time your insert query is executed, it will result in the trigger being fired again and goes on infinitely.

Comment: @e4c5 uh one last thing , i have updated my code above. i just noticed that everytime i update the  ratings table,  every update goes through , it lets people who havent rented a certain movie to ti review it. maybe i removed the wrong thing. .

Comment: Because you are only raising a warning and not an exception. if you want to raise only a warning, you have to return NULL

Comment: @e4c5 ohhhh i got you , i had no idea the raising type had such an impact on the code. i thought it was just a sql way of out putting a message. now that i changed it to a exception it executes the constraints.

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `EXISTS()` version. (BTW: the definition for movies is missing)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rate_only_rented()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $func$
BEGIN
IF ( NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM rentals r
        JOIN discs d ON r.disc_id = d.id
        WHERE d.movie_id = NEW.movie_id
        AND r.customer_id = NEW.customer_id
        ) )  THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'you(%) have not rented this movie(%) before'
                             , NEW.customer_id             ,NEW.movie_id;
        RETURN NULL;
ELSE
        RETURN NEW;
END IF;
END;
$func$ language plpgsql;
```

---

And the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER rate_only_rented
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON ratings
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE  rate_only_rented()
        ;
```

Comment: i tested this to see a different way of don it , but when i run it it always adds the ratings record , regardless if somone has rented the movie or not.

Comment: Works here. Mine is a constraint/reject trigger. Yours is a "do instead" trigger. (I removed the `insert into ratings values (new.customer_id, new.movie_id, new.rating );` from the function, since that is the actual event causing the trigger to fire.

Comment: Oh, and I changed the trigger definition to `AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT`